# How to emoji react in SMS to iPhone users in Google Messages

Tags: sms, emoticons, rich-communication-services

I've tried searching online but haven't found an answer but is there any way to emoji react to SMS messages (Samsung Galaxy A53) on messages sent from iPhone users?

They are able to add emoji reactions to my messages yet I cannot do the same back.

I can to messages from some other contacts though, presumably those with Android devices.

I am using Google Messages and have all of the RCS chats enabled and verified.

Comment: Apple iPhones do not yet support RCS (Apple has just announced that the plan to support it). So most likely they are sending a simple SMS with the emoji and your messaging app converts that to an emoji reaction.

Comment: Related: [Google Messages Support - Google Messages emoji reactions to iPhone messages?](https://support.google.com/messages/thread/240423093/google-messages-emoji-reactions-to-iphone-messages)

Comment: @Robert I think they are able to actually react to the message with an emoji on iPhone rather than sending an emoji in a SMS reply...

Comment: @AndrewT. so it basically isn't possible then still it sounds like...?

Comment: To my knowledge the RCS integration into iOS iMessage app is still not public (if it yet works at all). Therefore Apple users can send SMS, MMS and iMessage. Android users can not receive iMessage thus only the other two remain to transmit the "emoji reactions".

Comment: Looks like it's still not possible, and looks like it's actually a "hack" done by Google (and Apple) as long as RCS is not supported on Apple. Related news: [Google Messages has started letting some users react with any emoji](https://www.theverge.com/2022/11/23/23475819/google-messages-any-emoji-reaction-test), "*'[emoji] to [message]' texts*". Related option: [Add reactions to messages](https://support.google.com/messages/answer/9827088), "*Show iPhone reactions as texts*".

Comment: Okay thanks for both your help on this.